# .NET Core with sub modules/paths written in different languages

Tags: c#, .net-core

Odd question and I can't find much on it, if anything. Perhaps my google fu isn't strong today. But if I were to create an overarching "framework"/app in .NET Core, is it possible to delegate subpaths or specific modules functionality to a different "program"/language.

For example: main app is .NET Core, module A is written in Go, module B is Python, etc?  If it is possible, how would one delegate the "routing" etc.?

Comment: .NET supports many languages.  Python is covered by [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/), Go is not afaik.  You can call .NET code from a Go program with [this wrapper](https://github.com/matiasinsaurralde/go-dotnet).

Comment: I've never heard of anything giving you this level of cross-language and cross-platform integration. Usually you have to do it by hand with scripts and the like. Even then, there's a question of how to integrate the different pieces... not so easy. Naturally, git does support having more than one language in a repository.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.  Might be easier to separate "modules" a different way or something.